# Why there are strips in the predicted image in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

In my test, I do two classes of segmentation in keras to mask cloud from satellite image.

Two samples for training and validation and testing, intentionally for overfitting.
The predicted image is very strange with strips like this(Right is predicted label. Left are image and label.):
[image]
[image]

My code is here.What's wrong with my code or is the problem of keras?

```
#coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D,UpSampling2D,BatchNormalization,Reshape,Permute,Activation
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop,Adadelta,Adagrad,Adam
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,LearningRateScheduler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from libtiff import TIFF
from skimage import exposure
from keras import backend as k
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
  
seed = 7  
np.random.seed(seed)  
  
#data_shape = 360*480  
img_w = 256  
img_h = 256  

n_label = 2  
  
classes = [0.  ,  1.]  
  
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()  
labelencoder.fit(classes)  
  
def load_img(path, grayscale=False, target_size=None):  
    img = Image.open(path)  
    if grayscale:  
        if img.mode != 'L':  
            img = img.convert('L')  
    if target_size:  
        wh_tuple = (target_size[1], target_size[0])  
        if img.size != wh_tuple:  
            img = img.resize(wh_tuple)  
    return img  
  
train_url = open(r'/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image4band16bit/train104/test4.txt','r').readlines()  
#trainval_url = open(r'/media/wmy/document/BigData/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/ImageSets/Segmentation/trainval.txt','r').readlines()  
val_url = open(r'/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image4band16bit/train104/test4.txt','r').readlines()  
train_numb = len(train_url)  
valid_numb = len(val_url)  
print "the number of train data is",train_numb  
print "the number of val data is",valid_numb  
  
directory = '/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image_block/image256/'
  
def generateData(batch_size):
    with open(r'/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image4band16bit/train104/test4.txt','r') as f:
        train_url = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]

    while True:
        train_data = []
        train_label = []
        batch = 0
        for url in train_url:
            batch += 1
#            img = load_img(filepath + 'JPEGImages/' + url.strip('\n') + '.jpg', target_size=(img_w, img_h))
#            img = img_to_array(img)
            tif = TIFF.open(directory + 'images/' + url + '.tiff')
            img = tif.read_image()
            mean_vec = np.array([456,495,440,446],dtype=np.float32)
            mean_vec = mean_vec.reshape(1,1,4)
            TIFF.close(tif)
            img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32)
            img = img - mean_vec
            img *= 1.525902189e-5
            # print img.shape
            train_data.append(img)
#            label = load_img(filepath + 'SegmentationClass/' + url.strip('\n') + '.png', target_size=(img_w, img_h))
            label = load_img(directory + 'labels/' + url + '.png', target_size=(img_w, img_h))            
            label = img_to_array(label).reshape((img_w * img_h,))
            # print label.shape
            train_label.append(label)
            if batch % batch_size==0:
                train_data = np.array(train_data)
                train_label = np.array(train_label).flatten()
                train_label = labelencoder.transform(train_label)
                train_label = to_categorical(train_label, num_classes=n_label)
                train_label = train_label.reshape((batch_size,img_w * img_h,n_label))
                yield (train_data,train_label)
                train_data = []
                train_label = []
                batch = 0

def generateValidData(batch_size):
    
    with open(r'/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image4band16bit/train104/test4.txt','r') as f:
        val_url = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    while True:
        valid_data = []
        valid_label = []
        batch = 0
        for url in val_url:
            batch += 1
            #img = load_img(filepath + 'JPEGImages/' + url.strip('\n') + '.jpg', target_size=(img_w, img_h))
            #img = img_to_array(img)
            tif = TIFF.open(directory + 'images/' + url + '.tiff')
            img = tif.read_image()
            mean_vec = np.array([456,495,440,446],dtype=np.float32)
            mean_vec = mean_vec.reshape(1,1,4)
            TIFF.close(tif)
            img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32) 
            img = img - mean_vec
            img *= 1.525902189e-5
            #print(img.shape)

            # print img.shape
            valid_data.append(img)
            label = load_img(directory + 'labels/' + url + '.png', target_size=(img_w, img_h))
            label = img_to_array(label).reshape((img_w * img_h,))
            # print label.shape
            valid_label.append(label)
            if batch % batch_size==0:
                valid_data = np.array(valid_data)
                valid_label = np.array(valid_label).flatten()
                valid_label = labelencoder.transform(valid_label)
                valid_label = to_categorical(valid_label, num_classes=n_label)
                valid_label = valid_label.reshape((batch_size,img_w * img_h,n_label))
                yield (valid_data,valid_label)
                valid_data = []
                valid_label = []
                batch = 0  
def SegNet():
    model = Sequential()
    #encoder
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(7,7),strides=(1,1),input_shape=(img_w,img_h,4),padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    #(128,128)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    #(64,64)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu')) 
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    #(32,32)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())    
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    #(16,16)

    #decoder
    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2,2)))
    #(16,16)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    #(32,32)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    #(64,64)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    #(128,128)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    #(256,256)

    model.add(Conv2D(n_label, (1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(Reshape((n_label,img_w*img_h)))

    model.add(Permute((2,1)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    sgd=SGD(lr=0.1,momentum=0.95,decay=0.0005,nesterov=False)
    adam = Adam(lr=0.001,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,decay=0.0005)
    #model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    return model 
  
  
def train():
    k.set_learning_phase(1)
    model = SegNet()  
    modelcheck = ModelCheckpoint('Segnet_params.h5',monitor='val_acc',save_best_only=True,mode='auto')  
    callable = [modelcheck]  

    history = model.fit_generator(verbose=2,
                                  generator=generateData(2),
                                  validation_data=generateValidData(2),
                                  steps_per_epoch=1, 
                                  epochs=600, 
                                  callbacks=callable, 
                                  max_queue_size=1, 
                                  class_weight = None,
                                  validation_steps=1)
    
    drawLoss(history)
    
def drawLoss(history):
    plt.figure()

    plt.plot(history.history['acc'],'g')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'],'r')
    plt.title('model accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'val'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
    # summarize history for loss
    plt.figure()
    
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'],'g')
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'],'r')
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
def predict():
    k.set_learning_phase(0)
    model = SegNet()
    model.load_weights('Segnet_params.h5')
    file = open(r'/media/private/yanyuan/yan/image4band16bit/train104/test4.txt','r')
    train_url = [line.strip('\n') for line in file.readlines()]
    for url in train_url:
        tif = TIFF.open(directory + 'images/' + url + '.tiff')
        img = tif.read_image()
        TIFF.close(tif)
        mean_vec = np.array([456,495,440,446],dtype=np.float32)
        mean_vec = mean_vec.reshape(1,1,4)
        img = np.array(img, dtype=np.float32) 
        img = img - mean_vec
        img *= 1.525902189e-5
        im = np.empty_like(img)
        
        for j in range(4):
            
            l_val,r_val = np.percentile(img[:,:,j],(2,98),interpolation='linear')
            im[:,:,j] = exposure.rescale_intensity(img[:,:,j], in_range=(l_val,r_val),out_range='uint8')
            
        im = im[:,:,(2,1,0)]
        im = im.astype(np.uint8)
        img = img.reshape(1,img_h,img_w,-1)
        pred = model.predict_classes(img,verbose=2)
        pred = labelencoder.inverse_transform(pred[0])
        print np.unique(pred)
        pred = pred.reshape((img_h,img_w)).astype(np.uint8)
        pred_img = Image.fromarray(pred)
#        pred_img.save('1.png',format='png')
        label = load_img(directory + 'labels/' + url + '.png', target_size=(img_w, img_h))
        #print pred
        plt.figure()
        plt.subplot(2,2,1)
        plt.imshow(im)
        plt.subplot(2,2,2)
        plt.imshow(pred)
        plt.subplot(2,2,3)
        plt.imshow(label)
        plt.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    train()
    predict()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found the problem is that the epoch is not enough, when increasing the epoch from 600 to 1000, the result can be overfitting. But if do not scale the the data after mean substracting, 600 epochs is enough for overfitting.